# How to setup SSL module for google-app-engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I have followed [this](http://beautifulisbetterthanugly.com/posts/2009/aug/19/compile-ssl-115-python-25-or-lower) step-by-step and I have import successful when `cd` to `build\lib.win32-2.5`.

How to import it successful when I run `python` on other folders?

Comment: @zjm, I have updated my answer to explain your error when building ssl, but its for your local machine, you cannot use that module on google appengine.

Comment: @zjm, for the second question, you just need to install it by using `python setup.py install` after you did build OR just copy ssl folder from build\lib.win32-2.5 to `D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Regarding the error you got `cannot find -lgw32c`, you simply need to download [libgw32c](http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/libgw32c/0.4/libgw32c-0.4-lib.zip), which is mentioned in dependencies list on your [step by step guide](http://beautifulisbetterthanugly.com/posts/2009/aug/19/compile-ssl-115-python-25-or-lower/)

- [Openssl](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm)
- [libgw32c](http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/libgw32c/0.4/libgw32c-0.4-lib.zip)

=> developper Version!! (Not binaries, nor source ones)

I tried to compile with mingw32 too

```
D:\tmp\ssl-1.15> python setup.py build -c mingw32
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'ssl._ssl2' extension
writing build\temp.win32-2.5\Release\ssl\_ssl2.def
gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.5\Release\ssl\_ssl2.o build\temp.win32-2.5\Release\ssl\_ssl2.def -LC:\Utils\GnuWin32\lib -LD:\Python25\libs -LD:\Python25\PCBuild -lssl -lcrypto -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -lgw32c -lole32 -luuid -lpython25 -lmsvcr71 -o build\lib.win32-2.5\ssl\_ssl2.pyd -static
D:\tmp\ssl-1.15>
```

Importing ok

```
D:\tmp\ssl-1.15\build\lib.win32-2.5> python
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> dir(ssl)
['CERT_NONE', 'CERT_OPTIONAL', 'CERT_REQUIRED', 'DER_cert_to_PEM_cert', 'PEM_FOOTER', 'PEM_HEADER', 'PEM_cert_to_DER_cert', 'PROTOCOL_NOSSLv2', 'PROTOCOL_SSLv2', 'PROTOCOL_SSLv23', 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3', 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1', 'RAND_add', 'RAND_egd', 'RAND_status', 'SSLError', 'SSLSocket', 'SSL_ERROR_EOF', 'SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE', 'SSL_ERROR_SSL', 'SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL', 'SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT', 'SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ', 'SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE', 'SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP', 'SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__path__', '_fileobject', '_getnameinfo', '_ssl2', 'base64', 'cert_time_to_seconds', 'get_protocol_name', 'get_server_certificate', 'os', 'select', 'socket', 'sslwrap_simple', 'sys', 'wrap_socket']
>>>
```

**Update**: for the second question

> my new problem is : how to import it
>   successful when i run 'python' on
>   other dirs?

In my example, I only did `python setup.py build -c mingw32`, you need to install it by using

```
python setup.py install
```

or

Just copy `ssl` folder from `build\lib.win32-2.5` to `D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\`

Comment: Your premise is wrong: He's trying to install the SSL module on his local machine, so appcfg, the upload tool, can use it to verify the server's SSL certificate when uploading new versions of his app.

Comment: @Nick, well, so do you think which part should I correct in my answer? Am I wrong troubleshooting his installation processes OR "telling him cannot load custom c extensions in Google App Engine" is wrong? OR suggesting to use Http is wrong? OR "answering him wrong at first place"?

Comment: anyway, going to remove first 2 lines

Comment: Telling him he can't load C extensions on App Engine was inaccurate (since he's not trying to). Answer looks good now.

Comment: Weirdly, SO let me remove the downvote, but won't let me add an upvote unless you edit it again.

Comment: Ok, I was assuming he want to use SSL on App Engine and installing it on his PC and (also thought he will try to install on App Engine too). Thanks for pointing out @Nick. I appreciated.

Comment: Yeah @Nick, thats by design. no problem, you can skip upvoting :-), thanks btw